# Firestore Searching

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, search, querying

I have a 'Users' collection containing documents named with UIDs. And each UID document has two collections, 'Documents' and 'UserDetails'.
'UserDetails' has a document called 'Basic' which contains a field called 'referralCode'. Now whenever a new user enters a refferal code, then I want to search my firestore database for the UID matching with that particular code. How can I acheive this?

Following are the pictures of the database for more clarity.

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

Comment: Since this is a sub-collection of the users collection, and you want to search across users, I think you'd need a collection group query. Here's a good [reference](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries). I haven't used those to find a single document before though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search across multiple (sub) collections of the same name, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Once you get a result in there, you can from the [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) navigate up to its `reference` and from there find the [`parent` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/parent.html) to find the exact collection path the result is in.

Comment: Can you please provide your answer with the code that will be much appreciated.

Comment: The first link in my answer shows example for all supported languages. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).